# Drupal theme - change slideshow images

Tags: image, drupal, drupal-7, slideshow

Using Drupal 7, "business" theme, I want to change the default slideshow images of the theme to my own images.

The documentation says:

> To change the Slide Images, Replace the slide-image-1.jpg,
>   slide-image-2.jpg and slide-image-3.jpg in the images folder of the
>   Business theme folder.

I did that, but images won't change. 
I changed the images in `sites/all/themes/business/images`. And kept these original names.
The old images are not there anymore, but slideshow still displays the old images.

I tried clearing Drupal cache, wasn't the problem.

I'm guessing maybe a wrong dir?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try clearing the cache in your own browser as I am pretty sure this is the correct directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is the correct directory for the slider images. Try clearing the cache in your own browser.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest, Don't go with hard-coded slideshow in theme, rather remove that slideshow from there and create new region. then create slideshow using view and flexslider which uses same CSS and javascript which makes you dynamic slideshow and you can add as many image you want.....